# Save values of dynamically created input

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to save my input data into `modulo.descripcion`. But it doesn't work. I just get back the initial values, not the new ones.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <label for="codigoInput" class="control-label">Descripción</label>
        <button type="button" onclick="addFields()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Agregar campos</button>
        <input style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" next-focus tabindex="0" placeholder="Escribe una característica del módulo" ng-repeat="d in modulo.descripcion" ng-model="d">
        <small class="help-block with-errors desc"></small>
    </div>
</div>
<a ng-click="saveEdit(modulo)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Guardar</a>
```

**JS**

```
function addFields() {
    var set = $('.desc');
    var length = set.length-1;
    $('<input style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" next-focus tabindex="0" placeholder="Escribe una característica del módulo" ng-model="d">').insertBefore($('small.desc'));
}
```

Comment: is it array modulo.descripcion?

Comment: @Shohel yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to insert a new object to modulo.descripcion array, that way the repeat will automatically populate the input, and you can also add the new item as an ng-model.

like that:

```
$scope.addField = function(){

modulo.descripcion.push({type:'number', value=''})

}
```